# Oracle SQL join with counts returning null

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, null

I'm having a problem with the following query in Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT t.diif, t.mlf_response, v.total
FROM t_temp_rows t
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT a.diif, s.mlf_response, COUNT(a.customer_terid) total 
FROM ter_details a 
INNER JOIN lieu_details s ON a.lieu_id = s.lieu_id 
WHERE a.customer_name = 'CUSTOMER_A' AND mlf_response IS NOT NULL  
GROUP BY a.diif, s.mlf_response) v ON v.diif = t.diif AND v.mlf_response = t.mlf_response;
```

t_temp_rows contains all possible combinations for diif and mlf_response, regardless of whether they actually return counts in the subquery or not. I am hoping to get a count for every row in t_temp_rows, including 0 for rows with no count (I will add the NVL once it actually works).

If I run the query, rather than returning the counts in 'total' where there is a value and null elsewhere, I get null for every row.

Expected:

```
diif        mlf_response        total
----        ------------        -----
ABCD        YES                 12
ABCD        NO                  32
ABCE        YES                 54
ABCE        NO                  01
ABCF        YES                 null
ABCF        NO                  null
```

Actual:

```
diif        mlf_response        total
----        ------------        -----
ABCD        YES                 null
ABCD        NO                  null
ABCE        YES                 null
ABCE        NO                  null
ABCF        YES                 null
ABCF        NO                  null
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using a different column in the count? for example, if you do count(a.diif) do you still get all the nulls? This may not be what you are looking to count, but testing to see what you get may help in finding a solution.

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that no rows in the subquery match `CUSTOMER_A`.

Comment: Is there a `CHAR = VARCHAR` join somewhere? Look for the datatypes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do not believe that is the case. If the subquery is returning data for the two other columns, then there must be some data.

Comment: @Jenn . . . The subquery isn't.  The first table is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, the subquery does return results like the following:

diif        mlf_response        total
----        ------------        -----
ABCD        YES                 6
ABCD        NO                  2
ABCE        YES                 2

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's not what the question says. 'If I run the suquery...'

Comment: @Jenn, that was a mistake, fixed in question now.

Also, no difference with count(a.diff)...

Comment: @user3589090: Okay. It made no sense before, because COUNT would never return NULL. So see what your derived table query v actually returns. Probably no records, as Gordon assumed. Then play with the where clause until it works.

Comment: Dear all, I can't respond to my own question yet, but:

Found the answer - t_temp_rows had spaces after the 'YES' and 'NO' values (as in 'YES ' and 'NO  '), which was preventing the matches.

Sorry to have wasted your time!

Comment: SO, was it because it is a `CHAR` column?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, both were varchar2(4), but the temp table was padded with spaces.

Comment: Hmm Ok great! Good Luck! I wrote a comment on `TRIM()` later removed it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `a.customer_name = 'CUSTOMER_A'` to the left outer join because by adding it to the where, you are making it an inner join.

```
SELECT t.diif, t.mlf_response, v.total
FROM t_temp_rows t
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT a.diif, s.mlf_response, COUNT(a.customer_terid) total 
     FROM ter_details a ON a.customer_name = 'CUSTOMER_A'
LEFT OUTER JOIN lieu_details s ON a.lieu_id = s.lieu_id 
WHERE mlf_response IS NOT NULL  
GROUP BY a.diif, s.mlf_response) v ON v.diif = t.diif AND v.mlf_response = t.mlf_response;
```

Comment: That's wrong. Table lieu_details which contains the field is inner joined to ter_details, so whether to put `mlf_response IS NOT NULL` in the WHERE clause or ON clause makes no difference.

Comment: Good point.  I updated it to make lieu_details a Left Outer Join.

Comment: Oh, I just notice, you talked about `a.customer_name = 'CUSTOMER_A'` whereas I mentioned `mlf_response IS NOT NULL`. Sorry. However the point is: The inner query (the derived table v) has no outer join. So there is no use in switching from WHERE to ON. And it seems that the OP thinks the inner join should return records, so to turn it into an outer join should not solve his/her problem.